# Get Data between two dates using Number as Identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make an SQL query in MS SQL Server where I put an account number to search and it gives me the data between the two date ranges.

code looks like this

```
select *
from transactions
where accountNo1 = '2005457846' transaction_date between '15-01-2018' and '18-01-2018'
```

Apparently what am i not doing correctly it tells me

> syntax error near transaction_date

Comment: `where accountNo1 = '2005457846' AND transaction_date between '15-01-2018' and '18-01-2018'`, i.e. a missing AND.

Comment: Thanks a Lot, works Fine here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add AND in the query.

```
select *
from transactions
where accountNo1 = '2005457846' and transaction_date between '15-01-2018' and '18-01-2018'
```

Comment: @Qalid Click the gray tick at the left side to mark this accepted if the reply solves your issue.

Answer (score -1):

use " and " also look date format

```
select * from transactions where accountNo1 ='2005457846' and transaction_date between '15-01-2018' and '18-01-2018'
```

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to learn how to use code block.